# adjust exported csv column width to its content

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

When exporting my ui-grid to csv, the columns all have the same width.

I need to adjust the width of the columns to the content , or at least having all of them exporting with a larger width.

I tried this but didn't work:

```
this.gridOptions = {
    exporterFieldCallback: function (grid, row, col, value) {
        col.colDef.width=500
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to change the width in CSV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the width of the column in the CSV file?

You can't set the width in a CSV, because it is a plain text file.